# Which port should I run WebSockets server on if 80 is already used by Apache?

Tags: apache, tcp, websocket, port80

I created a WebSockets app to provide communication between connected clients, but I'm concerned about corporate firewalls and ISP rules that might block the port 8080 it's using. But the usual HTTP port 80 (that really no one would block) is already used by Apache on that server to provide the functionality for the rest of the app (which is a clasic web app running on PHP).

What are my options there? Are my concerns misplaced?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set up an Apache reverse proxy to make your app available via port 80.  See (for example) [Running a Reverse Proxy in Apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies).

Comment: WebSockets are still not officialy supported by Apache reverse proxying.